# Scrollbar within a TextField Composable

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-compose-textfield

I am trying to add a scrollbar within a TextField() Composable that scrolls according to the text, something like this.

[image]

I am unaware of any existing in-built APIs to achieve this in a TextField() composable, nor was I able to find a custom implementation. I am using an older version of Compose and would like to keep it the same. The new version, I guess, has a TextField() implementation which accommodates a scrollbar within.

However, since I can't update the composable, it would be helpful if there exists any form of custom implementation (also out of curiosity).